# AppDelegate can redirect??I'm getting error delegate not method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking for the app delegate to redirect back to the main story if that is possible but i kept on stumble upon error that app delegate method doesn't work.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Daily Vibes"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay"
                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

        if([title isEqualToString:@"Okay"])
        {
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
            self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
            self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


        }
    }
```

I'm wondering is it possible to redirect them back to the main board when the click the UIAlertView

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Now it totally crashes with the top code . I don't know what is wrong , i checked everything is alright. Is it that hard to redirect back to the apps after UIAlertView??

Comment: Can you be more specific? "Totally crashes" and "top code" are meaningless. You need to show a crash log, any exception, and the line of code that crashes. Set an exception breakpoint if you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just setting the root view controller on the existing window should do it. You don't need to create a new window, and you don't need to make it key and visible.

You can animate the transition by using UIView transition or CATransition if you want to get fancy.

This does seem like an unusual thing to attempt, though - you'll lose any state or unsaved data and it might be quite odd for your user.

Comment: You mean something like this ?

UINavigationcontroller *nvc= = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
        self.window.rootViewController=nvc;

Comment: Yes, but if you're using a storyboard, the initial view controller thing you have already is fine.

Comment: Is this fine ?

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *initViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:nil];
            [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController pushViewController:initViewController animated:NO];

Comment: No. You won't get a view controller with no identifier. Like I said, the code in your question is fine except for recreating the window and setting it to key and visible.

Comment: Let's say for example i want to use identifier called dailymessage.
is this correct?

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
            dailymessage *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dailymessage"];
            
            self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;

Comment: Yes, that would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to present a view controller try something like the following:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Okay"])
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil]

    }
}
```